# How can I find out who filed for a patent?

Tags: us3535082

In reference to the patent: [US3535082](https://www.google.com/patents/US3535082)

Who filed this patent? Who was the patent attorney in the U.S.?

Answer (score 1):

> **Who filed this patent?**

**Applicant**:- Kernforschungsanlage Juelich

**Inventors**:- Hans Wolfgang Nurnberg, Gerhard Wolff

> **Who was the patent attorney in the U.S.?**

It seems that this applicant has taken many attorney services. Since they have filed two patent applications on same priority date i assume that they might not have changed the US attorney. In the matter of [US3558047](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?DB=EPODOC&II=15&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=19710126&CC=US&NR=3558047A&KC=A) having same priority date and context attorney was **Michael S. Striker** [OEDCI](https://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/) database states contact details as follows

[image]

its and assumption and analysis based answer might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know about the applicant of this patent by searching on espacenet.

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP

In regard to finding out the patent attorney - As this patent is very old, information about the attorney might not be available online. The best possible way could be to write an email to the USPTO to get information about the attorney who was working on this case.

Hope you find this useful!